# Async/await not executing in the expected order

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await

I am currently attempting to learn about MongoDB and asynchronous functions in javascript and have been messing around for the past few hours with no luck.

```js
async function getObj(name) {
  var db = await mongo.connect(DBURL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  });

  var dbo = db.db("testdb");

  var meme;

  await dbo.collection("files").findOne({
    "_id": name
  }, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res + " a");
    meme = res;
    console.log(meme + " b");
  });

  console.log(meme + " c");
  await db.close();
  console.log(meme + " d");
  return meme;
}
```

The program prints it in the order:
c
d
a
b

The query works fine where if I do console.log(res), I get the object with the right results so that isn't the problem.

Why does the program ignore the await that is before it and end up printing and returning undefined?

Comment: When the statement `console.log(meme + " c");` executes, what are you get?

Comment: As one answer mentions, you are not working with promises. Check out the docs [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findOne). Note the line `returns a Promise if no callback passed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using Promises that you can `await` when you use `db.findOne` with a callback. You should await it like so:

```js
async function getObj(name) {
  var db = await mongo.connect(DBURL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  });

  var dbo = db.db("testdb");

  var meme = await dbo.collection("files").findOne({
    "_id": name
  });

  console.log(meme + " c");
  await db.close();
  console.log(meme + " d");
  return meme;
}
```

Comment: But he uses `await` for the method `findOne()`, so the code should wait until it ends!

Comment: No, the code doesn't wait, there is not Promise returned to await, when using callbacks

Comment: But this code will wait until `findOne()` will end, even it doesn't get the result!

Comment: No, await transforms the result of that expression (undefined) to a fulfilled promise, this doesn't wait for anything to execute

Comment: If it did, the output would be in the correct order